# Tensorflow Object Detection Api (pip) Installation Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to install the TensorFlow Object Detection API on Google Colab:

```
!git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

%cd /content/models/research/
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

!cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
!python -m pip install .
```

And I get this error:

```
Collecting pyyaml<6.0,>=5.1 (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1.tar.gz (175 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I tried many things, including:

1. Installing without cache:

```
!python -m pip install . --no-cache-dir
```

2. Resetting/deleting runtime
3. Uninstalled all pip packages (hundreds):

```
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
!pip uninstall -r requirements.txt -y
```

4. Installing pyyaml separately (installs latest version successfully; the above script still fails)
5. `!pip install tf-models-official>=2.5.1`
6. `!pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on Windows and found [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/11051) post suggesting to use `PyYAML==5.3.1`.

So I edited the local `setup.py` and added it:

```
# vim models/research/setup.py
...
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [ 
    ...                                                                  
    'tf-models-official>=2.5.1',
    'PyYAML==5.3.1', # <- here
]
```

Comment: thanks it worked, I added 'PyYAML~=6.0',